# Debugging Javascript in Visual Studio 2012, stepping out of JQuery

Tags: visual-studio

I have a custom javascript which mostly does calls to JQuery UI and jqGrid.

I am debugging my code in Visual Studio with breakpoints.

When I step out of the code, it steps out into the main JQuery, JQuery UI, and jqGrid
libraries.  I have to step out again and again.

Each time I make a small change, I reload the script and step thru the code again and have to go thru this stepping out again and again...it is slowing me down.

Anyway I can avoid this?  I know some will say use Firebug or Chrome Development tools but I am really looking for a solution for Visual Studio because I would rather not have so many tools that I have to use for development.

Comment: ok I will use Firebug or Chrome, this is eating way too much of my time.  I have my custom script and jquery, jqueryui and jqrid and I have to step out over and over again.  HELP

Comment: Continue F5 instead of Stepping out 'Shift-F11'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue F5 instead of Stepping out 'Shift-F11'